# Marketo SFDC Sync

Tags: marketo

How to Stop Updating the Sync(Marketo to SFDC and vice-versa) on the First Name, Last Name and Account(Company) on Contact Object .

As far as I understand from the Marketo Documents that Sync for Contact object is automated for some Specific fields on contact

I have followed the Below approach :

Restrict the permissions on Integration user for Marketo To SFDC

1. I have provided read access and Edit access on contact.
2. I have unchecked the field level permissions on FirstName and
   LastName for Contact Object.